# Albin countergambit question about a line

Tags: opening, queens-gambit

In the albin countergambit, after this line:

1. d4 d5 2. c4 e5 3. dxe5 d4 4. e3 Bb4+ 5. Bd2 dxe3 6. fxe3 Qh4+ 7. g3 Qe4 8. Qf3 Bxd2+ 9. Nxd2 Qxe5
   [image]
   Why is the position better for black? Is it the fact that white has three pawn islands whilst black only has two? It's -1 for black according to stockfish and 60% winrate for black according to Lichess.

Is there a reason I'm not seeing?

Thanks!

Comment: I am supprised by the denomination "main line" for this poor way of handling the Albin... Isn't 4.Nf3 Cc6 5.g3 the old main line, and isn't 4.Nf3 Nc6 5.a3 the new main line ?

Comment: Oh yes, maybe I should edit it

Comment: You are correct about the pawn structure. Also black can develop with threats such as Nf6 bg4 if white now castle to protect b2

Answer (score 2):

The main reason in my opinion is that white has (scatteredly) expanded more than their position allows them to. it's important to keep a tight structure in these situations, which they have not managed to do.

In fact, their king is in danger for two reasons:

- They need at least three tempis to castle, since queenside castle looks very dangerous
- The main defender of their position, the essential e pawn, is isolated and can be defended for now only by their queen, so it already is a target.

In essence, black is ready to launch an attack and white is probably already late to defend.